# How can I sort time in dataframe in terms of hour,minute,seconds and milliseconds?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a problem about sorting time including hour,minute,seconds and milliseconds as ascending.

In my dafaframe, time column has defined as shown below. ( `df['Time'].unique()` )

```
array(['2:13:23.600', '3:13:18.700', '2:02:53.700', ..., '1:33:55.653',
       '1:33:14.678', '1:34:05.715'], dtype=object)
```

Time is also included this kind of variables such as `42:53.700 , 5:30.622 , 10.111`

How can I sort this column?

Here is my screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
a = np.array(['2:13:23.600', '3:13:18.700', '2:02:53.700', '1:33:55.653',
              '1:33:14.678', '1:34:05.715'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':a})

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df = df.sort_values('Time')
print (df)
             Time
4 01:33:14.678000
3 01:33:55.653000
5 01:34:05.715000
2 02:02:53.700000
0 02:13:23.600000
1 03:13:18.700000
```

Another idea with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for array of position and for change order pass to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), but because multiple format create multiple `Series` for handle each of them, join together by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace non matched values (missing values):

```
a = np.array(['2:13:23.600', '3:13:18.700', '2:02:53.700', '1:33:55.653',
              '1:33:14.678', '1:34:05.715', '42:53.700' , '5:30.622' , '10.111'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':a})
```

---

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
d3 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%S.%f', errors='coerce')

d = d1.fillna(d2).fillna(d3)
print (d)
0   1900-01-01 02:13:23.600
1   1900-01-01 03:13:18.700
2   1900-01-01 02:02:53.700
3   1900-01-01 01:33:55.653
4   1900-01-01 01:33:14.678
5   1900-01-01 01:34:05.715
6   1900-01-01 00:42:53.700
7   1900-01-01 00:05:30.622
8   1900-01-01 00:00:10.111
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Check if all values are converted, so here is nonecessary empty Series:

```
print (d[d.isna()])
```

Series([], Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns])

And last change order:

```
df = df.iloc[d.argsort()]
print (df)
          Time
8       10.111
7     5:30.622
6    42:53.700
4  1:33:14.678
3  1:33:55.653
5  1:34:05.715
2  2:02:53.700
0  2:13:23.600
1  3:13:18.700
```

Comment: I try it but it throws this error ( ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format before .)

Comment: Time column also covers this kind of time 42:53.700 , 5:30.622 , 10.111, and so on

Comment: @TonyBrand - Super, glad can help!

Comment: @TonyBrand - Sure, don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: @TonyBrand - I test it under win, also install `imgkit` and `wkhtmltopdf` and it failed :(. I got error `OSError: No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org`. Maybe working under linux, I guess.